# Why the slider image is not responsive?

Tags: css, slider, responsiveness

The problem seems to come from the ul.gallery with that width of 20000em.

Even if the rest of the divs are resizing, the images are not.

here a live test; (edit: removed link)

Any help please?

```css
#container div.school {
  background: white;
  color: #333333;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#container div.school ul.gallery {
  float: left;
  width: 20000em;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container div.school ul.gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 800px;
}

#container div.school ul.gallery li .image {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container div.school ul.gallery li .image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="schools">
  <div class="school" id="sass">
    <ul class="gallery">
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a class="swipebox" title="School of Arts and Social Sciences 1" href="http://s1.city.ac.uk/developer-assessment-2015/i/sass/01_2048x1396.jpg"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://s1.city.ac.uk/developer-assessment-2015/i/sass/01_tn.jpg" alt="School of Arts and Social Sciences 1" title="School of Arts and Social Sciences 1" width="600" height="409"></a>
          <div class="caption">School of Arts and Social Sciences 1</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="jcarousel-control-prev" href="#">‹</a>
    <a class="jcarousel-control-next" href="#">›</a>
    <div class="jcarousel-pagination"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Edit: The images now resize, after setting the viewport width to 100% in media queries.

Comment: try to add mediaquery for this on `#container div.school ul.gallery li` and check plz.

Comment: Thanks, Akhil, but nope. I have tried with a different width in px, then 100%, max-width etc but no success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a strictly CSS solution you can set the max-width of your list items to 800px and width to 100vw (% of viewport width). [Viewport unit browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

```css
#container div.school ul.gallery li {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100vw; /* sets width to 100% of viewport width */
}

#container div.school ul.gallery li .image {
    padding: 0 10%; /* add if you want padding on images */
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you, IMI, it worked. I wish I could vote you up.

Comment: Glad I could help. Even if you can't upvote you should still be able to click the check mark to accept this as the answer to your question. ;)

Comment: Done. So many options, rules, etc that it is  like to learn a new language in here. :)